# From big array to two small ones

Tags: java, arrays, int

So im trying to make from one big array with numbers of 20, and two little ones of 10, the second array have to outprint hes vallue.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
       int[] bMas = new int[20];

        int[] lMas = new int[10];
        int[] lMas2 = new int[10];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < bMas.length; i++)
        {
            bMas[i] =  in.nextInt();
        }
         // 0 10
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lMas[10 - i] = bMas[10];
        }
        //10 20
        for(int i = 10; i < bMas.length; i++)
        {
            lMas2[10 - i] = bMas[20];
            //Here he must outprint hes vallue
           System.out.println(lMas2[i]);
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Ok.  But what is the specific problem/question?

Comment: You'll have a lot more success if you actually ask something.

Comment: so what is your problem ?

Comment: `lMas[10 - i] = bMas[10];`  should be give array out-of index at i= 0

Comment: Im trying to input my numbers, then get out of last array lMas2 vallues which i putted in big array arround 10-20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

```
lMas[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(bMas, 0, 10);
lMas2[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(bMas, 10, 20);
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy without acctually using this function?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your question is (mainly because you didn't ask one) but I can tell right off that you're getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        lMas[10 - i] = bMas[10];
    }
```

This loop is going to give you an index out of bounds error the first time in. The array lMas is 10 units large (index 0-9) so when i = 0 this is going to be referencing index 10 which does not exist.

Even if that was correctly written you're storing the exact same bMas[10] value into every slot of the lMas array.

You do the exact same thing to the lMas2 array.